# electron forge not making exe

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

im useing the latest version of electron forge to make my app, so to make sure that the setup worked i ran the make command and it didn't work.

error:

PS D:\javascript\testing\New folder> cd my-app
PS D:\javascript\testing\New folder\my-app> npm run make

> my-app@1.0.0 make D:\javascript\testing\New folder\my-app
> electron-forge make

✔ Checking your system
✔ Resolving Forge Config

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Could not find module with name: @electron-forge/maker-squirrel. Make sure it's listed in the
devDependencies of your package.json
at _default (D:\javascript\testing\New folder\my-app\node_modules@electron-forge\core\src\api\make.ts:132:15)
at D:\javascript\testing\New folder\my-app\node_modules@electron-forge\cli\src\electron-forge-make.ts:44:5

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@1.0.0 make: `electron-forge make`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@1.0.0 make script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\nycas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-04T01_06_58_366Z-debug.log
PS D:\javascript\testing\New folder\my-app>

i have @electron-forge/maker-squirrel and its a brand new project that I literally just made

help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running npm run package ?

Comment: yes, i have tried running package

Comment: @electron-forge/maker-squirrel is not found as a dev Dependency

Comment: i re imported the dev squirrl dependency manualy and it still could ent find it